# Javascript assistance with lightbulbs and canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  I am trying to have the bulbs animate and turn on with clicking them in the Canvas.  I've got it to work outside the canvas, but not inside.  Is there something I am missing.  I am new to programming.  Also if possible, any recommendations to have the the background be black and then the light bulbs turn on the canvas.  Basically, a night time type mode to a the lights bulbs being a day time mode.  I saw examples, but wasn't sure if they could easily be implemented in my current code.

```
   <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
   shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Rummage it All</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/homework.css">
    <style>
    #canvas{
        background-color: black;
    }
</style>

 </head>

 <body>
<!--Navigation to different links and parts of the website-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Rummage Store</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Products</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Rummage Items</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Unique Items</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Love that Ink Pen Company</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown02" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Who we are</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">About Us</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Our Vision</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown03" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Links</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/home.html">Home</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week1-1.html">Week 1-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week1-2.html">Week 1-2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week2-1.html">Week 2-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week2-2.html">Week 2-2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week3-1.html">Week 3-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week3-2.html">Week 3-2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week3-3.html">Week 3-3</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week4-1.html">Week 4-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week4-2.html">Week 4-2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week5-1.html">Week 5-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week5-2.html">Week 5-2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week5-3.html">Week 5-3</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week6-1.html">Week 6-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week6-2.html">Week 6-2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week7-1.html">Week 7-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week7-2.html">Week 7-2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week8-1.html">Week 8-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week8-2.html">Week 8-2</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>

<main role="main">

    <!--Main jumbotron-->
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="display-3" style="text-align:center">Rummage Items</h1>
        </div>
        <!--Card to display a logo-->
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem; color:black">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="../images/week2-1logo.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
                <p class="card-text">Rummage it</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!--Improved columns--->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <img id="light" width="25" height="25" src="../images/bulboff.gif" onclick="lightbulb()"  />
            <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="650"></canvas>
         </div>
      </div>
    </main>


<!-- Footer Information -->

<div class="footerb">
    <p>&copy; Rummage it All</p>
</div>



<script>
    //introduction
    var title = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = title.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = "24px Arial";
    ctx.fillText("Hello Rummagers", 30, 40);

    var para = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = para.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = "14px Arial";
    ctx.fillText("We are so happy that you found our interactive lamps, click the submit button to determine if your a lucky winner of a prize", 30, 80, 800);

    //legs
    var legs = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = legs.getContext("2d");

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = "25";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "brown";
    ctx.moveTo(250,350);
    ctx.lineTo(250,600);
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = "25";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "brown";
    ctx.moveTo(650,350);
    ctx.lineTo(650,600);
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = "25";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "brown";
    ctx.moveTo(750, 350);
    ctx.lineTo(150, 350);
    ctx.stroke();

    //Lamp1 base
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(250, 340);
    ctx.lineTo(325, 340);
    ctx.lineTo(325, 325);
    ctx.lineTo(250, 325);
    ctx.fill();

    //Lamp1 Shaft
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(285, 325);
    ctx.lineTo(285, 260);
    ctx.lineTo(295, 260);
    ctx.lineTo(295, 325);
    ctx.fill();

    //Lamp1 Shade
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(240, 260);
    ctx.lineTo(340, 260);
    ctx.lineTo(305, 190);
    ctx.lineTo(270, 190);       
    ctx.fill();

    //Lamp2 base
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(575, 340);
    ctx.lineTo(650, 340);
    ctx.lineTo(650, 325);
    ctx.lineTo(575, 325);
    ctx.fill();

    //Lamp2 Shaft
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(610, 325);
    ctx.lineTo(610, 260);
    ctx.lineTo(620, 260);
    ctx.lineTo(620, 325);
    ctx.fill();

    //Lamp2 Shade
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(565, 260);
    ctx.lineTo(665, 260);
    ctx.lineTo(630, 190);
    ctx.lineTo(595, 190);
    ctx.fill();

    //Lamp Lights
        var bulb1 = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx = bulb1.getContext("2d");
        var img = document.getElementById("light");
            ctx.drawImage(img,600,183,25,25);

        var bulb2 = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx = bulb2.getContext("2d");
        var img = document.getElementById("light");
            ctx.drawImage(img, 276, 183, 25, 25);

    //Light Bulbs work
            function lightbulb() {
                var image = document.getElementById('light');
                if (image.src.match("bulbon")) {
                    image.src = "../images/bulboff.gif";
                } else {
                    image.src = "../images/bulbon.gif";
                }
            }      
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue? What's wrong with this code, and what's missing?

Comment: I am trying to have the light bulbs light up in the canvas and they are not. They lit up outside just fine, but they won't inside the canvas